# background in canvas become transparent when media stream on pair isn't avaible

Tags: android, peerjs

What I want is when pair media stream isn't available is should just display black but now background in Peer JS canvas become transparent when media stream on pair isn't available in android
no matter what I do, even when I try to put a layout on back on it it is still override by the transparent canvas

pleease help me

https://gyazo.com/9215c8d69b68e2a2df4e2f53770e402c

https://gyazo.com/c0e46f0e8b71477fcb2b53d7733e2e5b

but when the pair reconnected it just immediately fill the canvas becomes not transparent anymore

sorry for my bad english